# array fetch in a random way PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

In my `$data` array i have some data stored. So when i try to search for something which is in the right direction my function can find within the array.

For example ---

```
Suppose i am looking for **Samsung Galaxy S** from my array $data, 
it will return the value 1, 2 and 4 from the array
```

**but the problem is i want to find in data in a random way.
like - "S Galaxy Samsung"**

But the data is stored like - Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II 
so when i search for **"Samsung Galaxy S"**, it actually find the value.
But when i search for **'S Galaxy Samsung'**, it can not find the value because we are finding in a random way.

But it should be found in the array, because the request data is there .

Anyone knows any solution for this problem !!!!

```
   function fetchDataAction() {
    $_POST = 'S Galaxy Samsung';
    $search = $this->my_array_search($data, $_POST); // $data is the array
   } 

function my_array_search($array, $string) {
    $pattern = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' .*', preg_quote($string));
    return array_filter($array, function ($value) use($pattern) {
        return preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $value) == 1;
    });
}


$data =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-N7100 Galaxy Note II 16GB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9100 Galaxy S II
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-i9300 Galaxy S III 16GB
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Apple iPhone 5 16GB
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-P5110 Galaxy S 4 10.1 16GB
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung UE46ES6715
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC128 128GB
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-N8000 Galaxy Note 10.1 16GB
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung 830 Series MZ-7PC256 256GB
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung UE46ES6715
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => Samsung GT-2423 Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 16GB
        )
```

Comment: it seems like full-text search within plain text. but how about creating recursive function that gets words -3 words from left and +3 words from right and does search on this chunk again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A text search tool like elasticsearch, lucene or sphinx may be better for larger scale applications.

If you want to use PHP, the below script will do a word by word comparison and return the index of the first row in $data that contains all the words. Duplicate words are only counted once. If no match is found then it returns -1.

```
function my_array_search($dataArray, $searchWords) {

    $searchWords=array_flip(explode(' ', $searchWords));
    $targetScore = count($searchWords);

    foreach($dataArray as $index=>$data) {

        $words=array_unique(explode(' ', $data['name']));
        $score = 0;

        foreach($words as $word) {
            if(isset($searchWords[$word])) ++$score;
        }

        if($score >= $targetScore) {
            return $index;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

An example usage would be

```
$matchId = my_array_search($data, 'S Galaxy Samsung'); 

Returns $matchId=1; // this is the first row in the sample data to contain all those words.
```

It's not the best solution because it may not scale or handle edge case such as misspellings. However you can probably adapt it to work for straightforward uses.